# mass image optimizer

Tags: php, html, image

I have a folder with about 5000 images in it.

I can use php, or software on a local version of the images if required.

Whats the best way to go through and optimize/shrink their size/compress them as quickly and efficiently as possible to 20 width and 20 height?

**Anything with a GUI that works on XP?**

Comment: If it's a one-off job, forget about PHP. Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: I really like one called FastStone Photo Resizer. Has portable version. Runs only on Windows, though...

Comment: The softwares look good, but is their anything with a GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools like `mogrify` or `convert` *(from [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php))* will do just fine, when it comes to resizing images.

After, if you want to optimize your images further *(reducing their size in bytes)*, you should take a look at software like :

- [**`optipng`**](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) or [**`pngcrush`**](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) for PNG,
- or [**`jpegtran`**](http://jpegclub.org/) for JPEG

If your goal is optimization for a website, take a look at [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site - Images](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#opt_images) and the points which follow *(I'm especially thinking about CSS Sprites)*

---

*Edit after edit of the OP :* hu... a GUI ? No idea, sorry *(I have those kind of tools run automatically, from scripts, on Linux servers)*.

Why not just write a script that will call those tools on all your images, and let it run for the night ?

Comment: Too scary.  Might end up wiping my harddrive like last time...GUI just seems safer...

Comment: Wiping your harddrive ? With those ? you'd have to very wrong for something like that to happen... *(and you could use some PHP code to generate the commands to execute those tools, reviewing the commands before executing them)*

Answer (score 1):

Use either of imagemagick or GD2 .. GD2 is already bundled in the newer versions (5.0+) of PHP. This way, you won't have to install new extension.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/) is what you are looking for.